# Average of group by count in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table that looks as follows:

| device | session |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | 1 |
| a1 | 1 |
| a1 | 4 |
| a1 | 5 |
| a1 | 5 |
| a1 | 5 |
| a2 | 1 |
| a2 | 2 |
| a2 | 2 |

I want to count the number of rows grouped by `device` and `session` and then get the average.

In pandas (or any tabular framework), I could do the following:

```py
df.groupby(['device','session']).size().mean()
```

I tried to replicate this logic in a measure:

```
avg_sessions = AVERAGE(
  COUNTROWS(
    GROUPBY(
      df,
      df[device],
      df[session]
    )
  )
)
```

but apparently, `GROUPBY` cannot be wrapped by `AVERAGE`:

> Parameter is not the correct type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this measure:

```
Average Group Count = 
VAR tbl =
    SUMMARIZE(
        YourTable,
        YourTable[device],
        YourTable[session],
        "Count", COUNTROWS(YourTable)
    )
RETURN
    AVERAGEX(tbl, [Count])
```

If you put this measure together with your *device* and *session* columns in a table, the result will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Peter! Thank you for your answer. I added a few more rows to the data.

Comment: Just updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Nice and clean!

Comment: You can use the same pattern with GROUPBY() too, but you have to replace the aggregation with `"Count", COUNTX ( CURRENTGROUP (), 1 )`. The new GROUPBY() is supposed to have a better performance on big data than the older SUMMARIZE().

Answer (score 0):

AverageX with GroupBy function can also be used to achieve the result.
If this is sample data and you need to perform this calculation on huge records then Dax need to optimize which can be discussed if required.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).